# Check a list inside a Map entry in a unit test using AssertJ

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertj

I want to check a list that is inside a Map value in a unit test using the AssertJ library:

```java
public class Group {
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public Group(List<Player> players) {
        this.players.addAll(players);
    }
}
```

```java
Map<Character, Group> generatedGroups = receiveFromAnyMethod();
```

Inside a Map I have this:

```
A: Group A -> players(playerA, playerB)
```

How I check a list inside a Group? I think I should use a extracting, flatExtracting methods, but I don't know how.

Comment: What do you mean “check a group”?

Comment: I mean get a list inside a group and check you size, for example. I need somehow to access the list inside a "Group" and working with it.

Comment: Do you know already which element of the map contains the group (and the inner list) you want to test, or do you want to check that at least one entry in the map has a list that satisfies your checks?

Comment: @StefanoCordio I already know which element will be taken. For example: I'll get a entry map passing 'A' key and then access the players list inside a "Group".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `character` is the input key, and `player1` and `player2` are the expected content of the inner list, you can write:

```
assertThat(generatedGroups.get(character))
  .extracting("players", as(InstanceOfAssertFactories.LIST))
  .containsExactly(player1, player2);
```

or with type safety, in case `Group` offers a `getPlayers()`:

```
assertThat(generatedGroups.get(character))
  .extracting(Group::getPlayers, as(InstanceOfAssertFactories.LIST))
  .containsExactly(player1, player2);
```

Reference:

- [`extracting(String, InstanceOfAssertFactory)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.lang.String,org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory))
- [`extracting(Function, InstanceOfAssertFactory)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.util.function.Function,org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory))
- [`Assertions.as(InstanceOfAssertFactory)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#as(org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory))
- [`InstanceOfAssertFactories.LIST`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/InstanceOfAssertFactories.html#LIST)
- [`InstanceOfAssertFactories.list(Class)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/InstanceOfAssertFactories.html#list(java.lang.Class))

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Map.Entry<Character, Group> entry : generatedGroups.entrySet()) {
    
    List<Player> players = entry.getValue().getPlayers();
    // Do your check here
}
```

Comment: My question was edited and removed from title "AssertJ". I want to do this using AssertJ library.

Comment: anyway, i showed you how to access the list inside your map. Now do all the checks you want. If you don't know how to use AssertJ I'm sure there are plenty of exemples all around the web. Like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042592/asserting-properties-on-list-elements-with-assertj

Comment: My question is only about using AssertJ library, and I already searched about this topic and founded not about it. Maybe I didn't make clear that this question is about testing, sorry.

Comment: @KauanMocelin That edit was done (by me) because including tags in the title like you did should not be done. That is what the tag system is for. You didn't mention AssertJ explicitly in the body of the question, so I have edited your question to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Below is slight different answer with specific use case.

We wanted to assert the existence of header in the Response object. Below is the unit test using AssertJ assertions to verify the headers `ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)`

```
assertThat(response).hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("statusCode", OK)
          .extracting("headers")
          .isInstanceOf(HttpHeaders.class)
          .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("Content-Type",List.of(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
```